# Puppet no implicit conversion of string into integer

Tags: puppet, varnish

I am using puppet to manage a varnish server with multiple backends. I am trying to create a loop so that additional backends can be added at a later date. So far I have the following in the erb file:

```
<% @backends.each do |backend| -%>
backend <%= backend['backend_name'] %> {
    .host = "<%= @backend_addr %>";
    .port = "<%= backend['backend_port'] %>";
    .connect_timeout = 600s;
    .first_byte_timeout = 600s;
    .between_bytes_timeout = 600s;
}
<% end -%>
```

But when this is run I get the error:

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Failed to parse template varnish/drupal.vcl.erb:
  Filepath: /etc/puppet/modules/varnish/templates/drupal.vcl.erb
  Line: 17
  Detail: no implicit conversion of String into Integer
 at /etc/puppet/modules/varnish/manifests/init.pp:22 on node x.x.x.x
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which is line 17 of the template?

Comment: You index each element of `@backends` (as `backend`) as a hash, with string indexes.  If one of the backends is an array instead then you might see such an error.  Otherwise, I don't see what might be wrong.